# For some reason, changing volume in js created Audio object doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, audio, html5-audio, web-audio-api

What could be the issue?
Setting the volume to 0 makes the audio mute, but any float number just doesn't work.
Any float number in the volume attribute just plays it 100% volume.

```
const colorsAudio = {};
colorsAudio.red = new Audio("sounds/red.mp3");
colorsAudio.red.volume = 0.2;
colorsAudio.blue = new Audio("sounds/blue.mp3");
colorsAudio.blue.volume = 0.2;
colorsAudio.green = new Audio("sounds/green.mp3");
colorsAudio.green.volume = 0.2;
colorsAudio.yellow = new Audio("sounds/yellow.mp3");
colorsAudio.yellow.volume = 0.2;
const wrong = new Audio("sounds/wrong.mp3");
```

```
function playSound(name) {
    colorsAudio[name].play();
}
```

Here is the snippet of code that I use.
The function is called on the button click event

```
$(".btn").click(function (event){
    if(old_timestamp == null || old_timestamp + 200 < event.timeStamp)
    {
        playSound(userChosenColor);
        old_timestamp = event.timeStamp;
    }
});
```

Comment: It's working fine here in isolation: https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/Luzd94bh/. Make sure that the Audio element you're changing the volume of is the same as the one you actually start playing. If you need more debugging help, then we need to see a complete example of the code which creates the issue

Comment: have you found a solution? I've got exactly the same problem.